# Change the Image view if GPS, WIFI, BLUETOOTH is ON

Tags: android, gps, bluetooth

I have 3 Image views for GPS,WIFI,BLUETOOTH  and I want to change the  background Image of each imageview if  GPS,WIFI,BLUETOOTH  is ON (programmatically)

The image should get changed if GPS, BLUETOOTH is on otherwise no

I tried but its not working

final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
   gpsimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);

            gpsimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.gps);

            }else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                gpsimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.gps);
            }

    }
});
```

Bluetooth code is here

```
     mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(!mBtAdapter.isEnabled())
    {

        bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_grey);
         Log.i(TAG ,"BLUETOOTH DISABLED") ;

    } 
            bluetoothimg.setOnClickListener(new View. OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
             bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setImageResource` before calling `startActivityForResult` and `startActivity` as:
For GPS:

```
gpsimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.gps);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

and for Bluetooth:

```
 bluetoothimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt);    
 startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! its working and onclicking on the same button(after gps ,wifi are enabled)  how can we turn off them and change the image view as it was earlier

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bluetoothimg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.bt));
```